# How can I use Ruby code in a buildr project?

Tags: ruby, scala, clojure, buildr

How can use Ruby in a buildr project?

I've used Ruby, JRuby, Java, and Clojure in quite a few separate projects. I'm currently working on a simulation app in my standard Ruby that I wanted to try to do with a Clojure backend (I do enjoy the functional code), and JRuby gui and test suite. I could also see using say, Scala, for the backend in a different project in the future.

I think I'm going to give buildr (http://buildr.apache.org/) a try for my project, but I noticed that buildr doesn't seem to be set up to use JRuby code inside the project itself! This seems a little silly, seeing as the tool is meant to unify the common JVM languages and is built **in** ruby.

Does anyone know how you would accomplish this, short of including the outputted jar in a distinct, ruby only project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not very specific about how you want to use your (J)Ruby code so I'll give you one example out of many possible approaches.

Let's create a directory structure and put Java and Ruby files in it,

```
.
├── buildfile
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── Foo.java
        └── ruby
            └── app.rb
```

with the content of `Foo.java` as follows,

```
public class Foo {
  public int bar() {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

and a simple `app.rb` startup script,

```
puts "Foo.bar is #{Java::Foo.new.bar}"
```

Your `buildfile` would look somewhat like,

```
VERSION_NUMBER = "1.0.0"

repositories.remote << "http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2/"

JRUBY = "org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:1.6.3"

define "ruby-example" do
  project.version = VERSION_NUMBER
  project.group = "org.example"

  run.with JRUBY
  run.using :main => ['org.jruby.Main', _(:src, :main, :ruby, "app.rb")]
end
```

(the `run` task is documented at http://buildr.apache.org/more_stuff.html#run)

and you can now run your application by typing,

```
$ buildr run
```

and get the following output,

```
$ buildr run
(in /home/boisvert/tmp/ruby-example, development)
Foo.bar is 42
Completed in 1.884s
```

Comment: Okay, that does work for running it in buildr. But when I package as a jar and try to run, it says that it fails to load the Main class attribute from the manifest file.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Does this example pertain to a specific version of jruby?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [buildr to use JRuby](http://buildr.apache.org/installing.html#jruby).

Comment: That link explains how to get buildr to use JRuby, not how to use buildr to build JRuby projects.